# Ant: NoClassDefFound exception

Tags: java, apache, ant, build.xml

I am developing a java project. My instructor wants us to strictly use apache ant for compilation. I knew nothing about it, and don't know about apache ant either. I have generated an ant buildfile and edited that for target "run", so that program will run after ant run command.

I am getting following error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: src/Client
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.Client
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
     [java] Could not find the main class: src.Client. Program will exit.
```

I think I have resolved all the target dependencies. But still this error persists.

Can somebody help me? This is my ant build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
              Any modifications will be overwritten.
              To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
              directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
              as the first entry and export the buildfile again. -->
<project basedir="." default="build" name="client">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../../../usr/lib/eclipse"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.6"/>
    <path id="client.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="libthrift-1.0.0-javadoc.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="libthrift-1.0.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="log4j-1.2.14.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <mkdir dir="build"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
    <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
    <target name="build-subprojects"/>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="client.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target name="jar" depends="init">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar" />
        <jar destfile="client.jar" basedir="bin">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="src.Client" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
    <target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
    <target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
    </target>
    <target name="Client">
        <java classname="Client" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
            <classpath refid="client.classpath"/>
        </java>
    </target>
    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="client.jar" fork="true">
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Can anybody spot the mistake for me?

Comment: in the client.classpath add src path also. and try.

Answer (score 2):

`Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` occurs when some class, yours or in a library your code depends on, try to use a symbol not already loaded. The class loader use the java path `package_aa.package_bb.SomeClass` as a key into the set of of classes it knows, specified by -classpath or -cp. In your case this "repository is `bin, libthrift-1.0.0-javadoc.jar, libthrift-1.0.0.jar, log4j-1.2.14.jar, slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar`.

In your context, when the class p1.p2.Client is about to be loaded, the classloader looks for bin/p1/p2/Client.class, look for /p1/p2/Client.class into each jar and when all the search paths are exhausted, the exception is thrown.

In this part of your build.xml :

```
<target name="jar" depends="init">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar" />
    <jar destfile="client.jar" basedir="bin">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="src.Client" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

`value="src.Client"` is wrong, it should be the logical java path i.e. the package + the class name. src is a directory not a package. If you haven't any package, it's just classname.

I presume

```
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="Client" />
```

That should do the trick.

Reference:

- [Apache ANT Manual for Jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html).
- [Oracle Jar Tools Manual (entry point)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html#entrypoint)

**EDIT** after first debug, the second error appears:

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="client.jar" fork="true">
    </java>
</target>
```

Can't work because Client.jar is not autonomous, it requires a lot of depndencies, which aren't specified here. You should use the classpath ref defined on top of your build.xml.

It *may be* wrote as:

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java classpathref="client.classpath" fork="true" classname="Client" />
</target>
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransportException

Comment: Can you please give me a Hint about NoClassDefFound or ClassNotFoundException? Root cause of it? Any hint that I can use to remove it?

Comment: Post edited, if you are satisfied don"t forget to accept it! ;-)